# Coldfusion, facebook integration

Tags: facebook, coldfusion

Really dumb question but I can not get this figured out. I'm trying to have users login to facebook via my site which uses coldfusion.

I'm trying to follow along through a simple tutorial posted here: http://jcreamerlive.com/2011/01/12/facebook-and-coldfusion/

I am just trying to read the cookie FB is supposed to return

my code is

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({appId: "XXXX", status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

// This is bascially code to subscribe to an event handler
// Any time someone does any sort of session change i.e. login, logout,
FB.Event.subscribe("auth.sessionChange", function(response) {

if (response.session) {
// A user has logged in, and a new cookie has been saved
window.location.reload();
} else {
// The user has logged out, and the cookie has been cleared
}
});
</script>
<fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<cfif isDefined("cookie.fbs_XXXX")>
<cfoutput>#cookie.fbs_XXXX#</cfoutput>
<cfelse>
0
</cfif>
</body>
</html>
```

So to me it looks like it is not receiving the cookie after a login.  If thats the case why not?
I know I am missing something conceptually

All I really want returned are the users name and profile picture which I can get if I get the uid.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

When ColdFusion creates cookies or looks for values in the COOKIE scope, it looks for uppercase variable names. So if you reference "cookie.fbs_XXXX" in ColdFusion, it looks for a cookie named FBS_XXXX. I think you can do this instead:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(cookie, "fbs_XXXX")>
    <cfoutput>#cookie["fbs_XXXX"]#</cfoutput>
<cfelse>
    0
</cfif>
```

I've not actually tested it but I think it is worth a try.

**Update:** I did test to see whether CF would find a lower- or mixed-case cookie with cookie.cookie_name and it will. Either cookie.cookie_name or cookie["cookie_name"] will work. So perhaps you have another issue entirely. Have you checked to see whether the window is actually reloading (i.e., that you're getting a response back from FB)?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at-

http://jamesconstable.co.uk/web-development/facebook-connect-library-for-coldfusion/